# Оптимизация MySQL SELECT запроса

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация, select

Друзья. Имеется следующий запрос:

```
SELECT CONCAT(p_sery, p_id) AS sery, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AS regulations_count, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM delivery WHERE p_id IN (SELECT regulation_id FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AND p_delivery_result = 1) AS delivery_count, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM delivery WHERE p_id IN (SELECT regulation_id FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AND p_delivery_result = 2) AS ND1, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM delivery WHERE p_id IN (SELECT regulation_id FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AND p_delivery_result = 3) AS ND2, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM delivery WHERE p_id IN (SELECT regulation_id FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AND p_delivery_result = 4) AS ND3, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM delivery WHERE p_id IN (SELECT regulation_id FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AND p_delivery_result = 5) AS ND4, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM delivery WHERE p_id IN (SELECT regulation_id FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AND p_delivery_result = 6) AS ND5, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM delivery WHERE p_id IN (SELECT regulation_id FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AND p_delivery_result = 7) AS ND6, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM delivery WHERE p_id IN (SELECT regulation_id FROM registry_regulations WHERE registry_id = a.p_id) AND p_delivery_result = 8) AS ND7 
FROM registries AS a WHERE (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(a.p_date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-01');
```

И следующая структура таблиц:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно оптимизировать данный запрос, на сервере он выполняется более 30 минут, очень много, все индексы имеются.
Результат EXPLAIN SELECT - на тестовом сервере записей в разы меньше чем на продакшн сервере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: На тестовом или продакшн сервере?

Comment: Запрос надо не оптимизировать, а полностью переписывать.

Comment: На том, где медленно.

Comment: Можете привести пример данных в виде `create table` и `insert`, надо же запрос на чем то проверять ...

Comment: Покажите `EXPLAIN SELECT` на сервере где много записей. Оптимизатор MySQL меняет план выполнения запроса в зависимости от числа записей в разных таблицах.

Comment: Связка двух id в registry_regulations уникальна ? т.е. не может быть двух записей с id (1,1) например.  А то я вижу у вас там отдельное поле под первичный ключ и оно уникальность связки явно не обеспечивает.

Comment: На продакшн сервере мне никто не даст доступы, там все оч серьезно, но там около 500000 записей

Comment: в registry_regulations содержатся значения id-реетра (registry_id) и id-постановления(regulations_id) у 1го registry_id может быть множество (regulations_id)

Comment: да вы пример из нескольких записей дайте, что бы можно было сделать новый запрос и сравнить результаты с вашим, что бы ничего не потерять

Comment: так вот у вас сейчас структура позволяет держать две записи с regulations_id=1 и registry_id=1, если на таблице нет уникального ключа включающего эти два поля. вот я и спрашиваю, возможны ли в БД реально такие ситуации

Comment: Возможны, такие ситуации, дело в том что изначально не требовались такие данные и таблицы не создавались под эти условия а теперь заказчик захотел эту фишку, а я не базист, вот и мучаюсь

Comment: Если вам никто на прод доступа не даст, вам следует набить тестовый сервер данными чтобы проверить что вообще запрос-то тормозит, или это может не в запросе дело? Может быть это кто-то на вас стрелки перевёл и мы с вами пытаемся лечить здоровое?

Comment: Ну а разве тот запрос который я написал правильный, я его писал на скорую руку, я сам не базист, но мне кажется что такие запросы писать нельзя, даже если они и работают)))) А столько данных мне не набить))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без примера данных сложно написать корректный запрос, для начала необходимо отказаться от подзапросов в `SELECT`. Приблизительно должно быть так:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(p_sery, p_id) AS sery, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT rr.id) as regulations_count, 
    SUM(d.p_delivery_result = 1) AS delivery_count,
    SUM(d.p_delivery_result = 2) AS ND1,
    SUM(d.p_delivery_result = 3) AS ND2,
    SUM(d.p_delivery_result = 4) AS ND3,
    SUM(d.p_delivery_result = 5) AS ND4,
    SUM(d.p_delivery_result = 6) AS ND5,
    SUM(d.p_delivery_result = 7) AS ND6,
    SUM(d.p_delivery_result = 8) AS ND7,
FROM registries AS r
JOIN registry_regulations AS rr on r.p_id = rr.registry_id
JOIN delivery AS d ON d.p_id = rr.regulation_id
WHERE r.p_date_created >= '2017-04-01' AND r.p_date_created < '2017-06-01'+interval 1 day
GROUP BY CONCAT(p_sery, p_id);
```

Comment: Думаю там время в дате есть из за этого они ее пытались в строку конвертить, так что `r.p_date_created >= '2017-04-01' AND r.p_date_created < '2017-06-01'+interval 1 day` и еще мне кажется что delivery по LEFT надо будет клеить. Но это конечно ТС виднее

Comment: @Mike подправил.

Comment: С учётом того, что это MySQL, я бы заменил `COUNT(CASE d.p_delivery_result WHEN x THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` на `SUM(d.p_delivery_result=x)`.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за замечание, поправил.

Comment: @vikolyada не COUNT(), а SUM().

Comment: Спасибо большое, говорят быстро отрабатывает

Comment: @Akina спасибо еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Раз, ваш запрос не использует индексы в таблице `registries` по колонке `p_date_created`.

В вашем плане запроса это прекрасно видно:

[image: не используется ключ]

Эта часть запроса будет выполняться для *каждой* строки в таблице:

```
WHERE (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(a.p_date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') 
       BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-01');
```

Ускорить в таких случаях можно добавив отдельную колонку под дату и сделав под неё индекс. В вашем случае колонка уже есть, непонятно только с индексами.

Вы можете искать сразу так, без преобразования дат:

```
WHERE a.p_date_created BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-01'
```

Два, неясна ситуация с индексом `p_id`. Из плана запроса можно сделать вывод что индекса по этой колонке нет.

Поможет переписать запрос или вообще делать всю работу вне MySQL, делая сколько нужно отдельных запросов, кешируя по возможности всё, что можно.

Comment: between с использованием индекса работает в разы быстрее, чем перечисление дат в IN. тем более, что когда в IN окажется пару десятков значений оптимизатор начисто откажется от использования индекса

Comment: Вы правы. В имеющейся версии MySQL у оптимизатора все хорошо с BETWEEN.